# How to generate seperate RESTful urls for edit and update in Backbone js model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm following Jame Yu's Backbone tutorial [here](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/) to create my own app. Below is my model. I wonder if there's a way to generate separate urls for edit and update (RESTful) instead of just 1 as in the tutorial. I use Rails on the back end. Thanks.

```
var BusinessCard = Backbone.Model.extend({

  url : function() {

    var base = 'business_cards';

    if (this.isNew()) return 'backbone/' + base;

    return 'backbone/' + base + (base.charAt(base.length = 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') 
    + this.id;

  }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the point of REST...the fact that there is *one* URI which responds to different verbs from the uniform interface (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), makes it restful. So Backbone is actually being RESTful, while you're not.

Answer (score 2):

The default backbone sync method works exactly how you want it to already by appending the models id to the url when performing an update.

If you need to customize how data is sent to your server I've found the best thing is to create your own backbone sync. Here is an example of how I do it to wrap my create and update requests in a root json object: https://github.com/codebrew/rails3-backbone-coffeescript/blob/master/app/coffeescripts/lib/mongo_model.coffee

Comment: Well, what about edit, the url is not gonna have /edit at the end and that's the problem. I can't figure out how to determine when a model is being edited.

Comment: /edit does not exist. It should be /model-name-plural/id as a PUT request and this is how backbone does it.

Comment: To add to @Julien's comment, you'd basically have some sort of routing server-side that can differentiate between a GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE. I use SLIM PHP which looks something like this in practice: $app->put('/modelName/:id', function($id) use($app) { // code that does the edit concept }); I have routing for all four HTTP request methods. When I want to create a model, I use POST. When I want to retrieve a model, GET. When I want to edit, I send a PUT request. When I want to obliterate a model from my DB, I send a DELETE. The server reacts appropriately according to the HTTP request.